# file inside a package

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to use the as3 `File()` method to import an xml into a file.

The file is inside my project in the package `resources/xml/baseXml.xml`

Now the File() method has several properties like:

```
applicationDirectory, applicationStorageDirectory, desktopDirectory, documentsDirectory
```

But none of them points me in the right direction. So how should i do this? To get the xml file inside the package?

I have tried to embed the file to be then i have a `Class` and not a `File`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you NEED to use File()? What if you were to just get the xml file with httpService?

Try:

```
<s:HTTPService url="resources/xml/baseXml.xml" result="yourResultHandlerToParseTheXML(event)"/>
```

Or you could just do:

```
<fx:XML source="resources/xml/baseXml.xml"/>
```

And parse off of that.

(Both would be located inside your  tags.

Unless you need an ActionScript only solution in which case the below SHOULD work:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.load("resources/xml/baseXml.xml");
```

Comment: the problem is that i need the file to perform importXML() wich is included in the indesign sdk, this only takes a File as a parameter

Comment: Is it looking for a file or a fileReference? Either way I think I am out of thoughts on this as I am not familiar with indesign but I would take a closer look at their documentation as well as the fileReference class from Adobe.